# Pentaho CDE - how to build a chart from an SQL query JDBC

Tags: postgresql, charts, pentaho, dashboard, pentaho-cde

I'm trying to understand the logic of Pentaho CDE

My goal is to have a bar chart from a PostgreSQL materialized view (3 columns: geo_name, cat_name, cat_value) (I don't need to go through OLAP cubes for the moment)

So at first I define on the Layout panel one row containing one column (name: col1)

I connect to my datasource via Datasources panel like this :

[image]

Query : select * from my_schema.my_materialized_view;

Then in the Components panel, I create a 'CCC bar chart' by filling in my datasource and the HTML object correctly but I don't understand where I can define the X, Y and value columns (as in Pentaho Report Designer)?
The Listeners property does not offer me anything.

In preview I get an 'Error processing component', how do I know if my data source is connected?

Thank you !

**EDIT SOLUTION**

Finally it was a driver problem, we must check that the driver JDBC PostgreSQL is present here: .../tomcat/webapps/pentaho/WEB-INF/lib (in my case the driver postgresql- 9.3-1102-jdbc4.jar)
And then on Pentaho CDE, in the sql over sqljdbc data source I put 'postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc4.jar' in the Driver property and it works!

Then you have to play with the query according to the type of chart and actually don't SELECT * FROM table

Comment: your query should be select a,b from tablename not select * from tablename..
it will take first column whichever you will specify on X-axis and it has not to be string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CCC charts by defaults takes first column on x axis and second column on y AXIS. Now this may be varies if you select crosstab property. If you want to change the axes as you want then you can select do it in post execution event of the ccc chart by setting properties.

Now for the data source connection, you can debug it through inspect the dashboard page and in Network you will see the cda query. also if it errors out then you can check it in console tab as well.

Another option is to check server/tomcat/logs directory you can verify pentaho.log and catlina.log for more information about the server behavior.